# Are Google Spreadsheets' first sheets always given an ID of 0?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using the Google Spreadsheets API and I'm curious as to whether or not the default first sheet, at the time of creating any new sheet, always has an ID of 0. I tried to research about this, but could not find any documentation regarding this.

Should I assume it will always be 0, or should I get it every time just to be on the safe side, in case they change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Situation 1:

When new Spreadsheet is created without the parameter for `sheetId`, the sheet, which is existing as the 1st index,  has the sheet id of `0` (`gid=0`) as the default value. In the current stage, this is the specification. For example, when the following request body is used to create new Spreadsheet, new Spreadsheet which has a sheet of "Sheet1" is created. And the sheet ID of "Sheet1" is `0`.

#### Request body:

```
{
 "properties": {
  "title": "SampleSpreadsheet"
 }
}
```

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets
```

### Situation 2:

When new Spreadsheet is created with the parameter for `sheetId`, the sheet ID can be given using the parameters. For example, when the following request body is used to create new Spreadsheet, new Spreadsheet which has a sheet of "Sheet1" is created. And the sheet ID of "Sheet1" is `123`.

#### Request body:

```
{
 "sheets": [
  {
   "properties": {
    "sheetId": 123
   }
  }
 ],
 "properties": {
  "title": "SampleSpreadsheet"
 }
}
```

#### Endpoint:

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets
```

### Result:

> Should I assume it will always be 0, or should I get it every time just to be on the safe side, in case they change it?

From above situations, the answer for your above question is as follows.

- When new Spreadsheet is created without using the property of `sheetId` for each sheet, the 1st sheet has the sheet ID of `0`.
- When new Spreadsheet is created with using the property of `sheetId` for each sheet, the 1st sheet can have also the sheet ID except for `0`.

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.