# Retrieving the number of sheets (tabs) from google spread sheet using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-sheets-api

I am working on a project need to fetch data from the spread sheet, But I need to loop through the
sheets (tabs) inside, and then get the data from.

The sheetId is dynamic, not fixed so I can't know what that sheet have inside regarding to the numbers of internal tabs.

Google API documentation not gives clear documentation.

Thanks, and hope I found solution for this.

```
        SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
        request.Fields = "namedRanges";
        // To execute asynchronously in an async method, replace `request.Execute()` as shown:
        var response = request.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every API method requires a `spreadsheetId` parameter which is used to identify which spreadsheet is to be accessed or altered. This ID is the value between the "`/d/`" and the "`/edit"` in the URL of your spreadsheet.

For example:

Spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=0
```

Sheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/aBC-123_xYz/edit#gid=sheetId
```

Of course, this requires you to type the URL.

If you want to get `Spreadsheet ID` and `Sheet ID` programmatically, you can use `spreadsheet.getId()` and `sheet.getSheetId()`(Need to call JavaScript):

```
function getIDs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var spreadSheetID = ss.getId();
  var sheetID = sheet.getSheetId();
  console.log(spreadSheetID);
  console.log(sheetID);
}
```

For more detail, you can check the documentation below：

[Google Apps Script, Google Sheets - Getting Spreadsheet ID and Sheet ID programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722597/google-apps-script-google-sheets-getting-spreadsheet-id-and-sheet-id-programm).

[Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

[Google Sheets and .NET Core with C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afTiNU6EoA8).

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi @Mohammad Rawwaqah, did my answer help you?