# How to automatically change links?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

The table (master) has links that point to cells within the table.
When creating a copy of this table (master copy), these links lead to the original table (master).
How can I automatically change the links so that they in the copy (master copy) refer to cells inside the copy (master copy)?
I'll link the script to the "fix links" button.
Link to table - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jrpjm7Yjwp-3WTFKyBz87laPeq6ksjwPaaiWWNcIoow/edit?usp=sharing

I think it can be done by replacing #gid (sheetID) in the links. I found information how to get #gid (sheetID) - [Google Apps Script, Google Sheets - Getting Spreadsheet ID and Sheet ID programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722597/google-apps-script-google-sheets-getting-spreadsheet-id-and-sheet-id-programm)
But I don't know how to automatically find and replace all #gid (sheetID) in the current table in the links.
You can do it manually using Find and Replace. But it needs to be automated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While links to external resources and other posts from this site might be helpful, please bear in mind that questions on this site should be self contained and that posts on this site are intented to be helpful to a broad audience, not only to the post author. Considering this please [edit] the questio to add the relevant parts of the linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your provided sample Spreadsheet, you want to change the hyperlinks in the range of "I6:I10" with the active sheet instead of the original sheet.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, as a test, please copy `master`, and please open the copied sheet. And then, please run this script. By this, the hyperlinks in the range of "I6:I10" are changed from the original sheet to the currently active sheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const checkRange = "I6:I10"; // This is from yoru sample Spreadsheet.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const range = sheet.getRange(checkRange);
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
    const link = c.getLinkUrl();
    return link ? c.copy().setLinkUrl(link.replace(/#gid\=.*&/, `#gid=${sheetId}`)).build() : c;
  }));
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, "master" sheet is copied to the same Spreadsheet with the specific sheet name, and the hyperlinks in the range of "I6:I10" are changed from the original sheet to the currently active sheet.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const newSheetName = "sample"; // Please set the new sheet name by copying "master" sheet.
  const checkRange = "I6:I10"; // This is from yoru sample Spreadsheet.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("master");
  const newSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(newSheetName);
  const sheetId = newSheet.getSheetId();
  const range = newSheet.getRange(checkRange);
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
    const link = c.getLinkUrl();
    return link ? c.copy().setLinkUrl(link.replace(/#gid\=.*&/, `#gid=${sheetId}`)).build() : c;
  }));
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your script works (script 1).
There are other links in the table. How can I modify the script to process multiple ranges - "I6:I10", "I212:I216", "I418:I422", "I625:I629", "I832:I836", "I1038:I1042"?
To copy protected sheets I use Hyde script - https://support.google.com/docs/thread/144274437?hl=en&msgid=144285010
A huge request to you - how to add your script 1 to the Hyde script?

Comment: @Badyr Thank you for replying. From `Thanks a lot! Your script works (script 1). There are other links in the table.`, I understood your issue was resolved. About `How can I modify the script to process multiple ranges - "I6:I10", "I212:I216", "I418:I422", "I625:I629", "I832:I836", "I1038:I1042"? To copy protected sheets I use Hyde script - support.google.com/docs/thread/… A huge request to you - how to add your script 1 to the Hyde script?`, I would like to support you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and support. On your advice, I created a new question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75097379/google-sheets-script-to-automatically-change-multiple-ranges-of-links)

Comment: Your script 1 stopped working. Didn't change anything. Checked again - created a new script and copied your code. Does not work. The other table also stopped working. I don't understand anything.

Comment: I apologize for my inattention. I tried to copy your script in broken links. Checked up on other table - works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time.