# Script to automatically change multiple ranges of links

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The "master" table has links to cells within that table. These are "I6:I10", "I212:I216", "I418:I422", "I625:I629", "I832:I836", "I1038:I1042".
How can I change these references so that when creating a copy of the "master" table, they refer to cells inside the "master copy"?
Maestro [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)  wrote a script that works. But I wrote a little incorrectly what is required of the script. Need to modify it so that it processes the ranges "I6:I10", "I212:I216", "I418:I422", "I625:I629", "I832:I836", "I1038:I1042"

```
function myFunction() {
  const checkRange = "I6:I10"; // This is from yoru sample Spreadsheet.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const range = sheet.getRange(checkRange);
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
    const link = c.getLinkUrl();
    return link ? c.copy().setLinkUrl(link.replace(/#gid\=.*&/, `#gid=${sheetId}`)).build() : c;
  }));
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

Link to table - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jrpjm7Yjwp-3WTFKyBz87laPeq6ksjwPaaiWWNcIoow/edit?usp=sharing

i tried to put in a script

```
const checkRange2 = "I212:I216";
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RangeList`, like this:

```
function replace() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['I6:I10', 'I212:I216', 'I418:I422', 'I625:I629', 'I832:I836', 'I1038:I1042']);
  rangeList.getRanges().forEach(range => modifyLinks_(range, sheetId));
}

function modifyLinks_(range, sheetId) {
  const richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues().map(row => row.map(value => {
    const link = value.getLinkUrl();
    return link ? value.copy().setLinkUrl(link.replace(/#gid\=.*&/, `#gid=${sheetId}`)).build() : value;
  }));
  range.setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now checked your script. It runs without errors. But does not change the links in the copy. Checked on the table in the description. And on other table.

Comment: I tested the script in a copy of your sample spreadsheet and it seems to work fine. The issue is with the links in your spreadsheet — not all cells that look like a link contain a link, and the rest may or may not be in the right format. The question you are asking is regarding how to apply an operation to multiple ranges. The answer deals with that through `.getRange().forEach()`. Whether the `.setLinkUrl()` bit works is out of scope of this question. If the original function you quote works for you, the code in the answer should work equally well.

Comment: I apologize for my inattention. I tried to copy your script in broken links. Checked up on other table - works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time.